# DashboardColumn disappears in Dashboard using PrimeFaces 6

Tags: primefaces

The showcase dashboard example doesn't work as expected. When having only a panel in 3rd column in my dashboard when I move it to 2nd Column, then the 3rd column disappears. Then, I am not able to move it back to the 3rd column since it disappeared. I tried looking around in a similar question posted but the solution offered there did work for me. I am using PrimeFaces 6 and copied the showcase example from here https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/dashboard.xhtml

Please help.

Comment: _"I tried looking around in a similar question posted but the solution offered there did work for me."_ please read [ask] about this... keep track, mention etc...

Comment: Tried the online showcase itself? Works perfectly... So pick your next steps...